# cronjob. run php only in a specified interval of time

Tags: php, cron

I have set up a cronjob that excutes a php script every 35 minutes. The issue is that I only want it to run from 11 AM to 2 AM the next day. I want this to be automatic without having to add # manually to the crontab.

I've tried putting something like this at the top of the php script :

```
$time = date(H);

if ($time < 23 & $time > 11)
{
   echo 'Working';
}
else
{
   echo 'Stopped';
}
```

But as you can see that only works on the same day.

**NOTE** The server is using another time zone which has +4 hours of difference with mine.

That means: 11 AM local time is 3 PM server time and 3 AM next day local means 7 AM next day server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want your cronjob to run between certain hours of the day? Have you tried:

```
35 11-23,0-2 * * * php /path/to/your/script.php
```

This will execute at 35 mins past every hour between 11am (day 1) and 2am (day 2) - everything is in server time.

Comment: whats the meaning of 11-23 and 0-2 here ? Please can you guide me.

Comment: And how to run it ? where to put this line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose `H` with quote marks:

```
$time = date("H");
```

Another way it is treated as constant, and, as you don't have such constant, `date()` receives empty argument

P.S. hohner provided better solution for you

Answer (score 0):

shift the times to the correct timezone before checking.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your code and apply some arithmetic, just substract 2 hours and you will have 9 to 23 instead of 11 to 23 + 0 to 2.

```
$time = date(H)  - 2 ;

if ($time < 23 & $time > 9 )
{
   echo 'Working';
}
else
{
   echo 'Stopped';
}
```

Try!

I guess your timezone is GMT-4, so 11 am to 2 am on your timezone will be 15 am to 6 am on the server; the other posible setup is you're talking on server time, which mean 11 am to 2 am is 7 am to 10 pm on your setup.

This mean it's possible you must adjust the code to substract 6 hours instead of 2.