# php - cron jobs to be triggered rather than at specific times and not repetitive

Tags: php, mysql, events, cron

I am new to cron jobs but used to php. In my application, I need to run a script/event that if an item is posted in MySQL db, after an hour it's status will change, from private to public, and after 24 hours it's status will change from public to expired. I tried to use the Mysql Schedule Events, It works well, but almost all shared hostings do not support it.

My Previous code:

```
                if($query==true){
                  mysqli_query($con,"CREATE EVENT ikiraka.act$id ON SCHEDULE AT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) DO UPDATE `ibirakas` set `status`='public' WHERE `id`='$id'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
                  header("location:view-post.php?kiraka_id=$id");
                }
```

The cron job I am aquanted with:

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /www/virtual/username/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

You can see what I am trying to do. So the cron jobs normally run a specific task at a specific time. How can I trigger a job rather than a normal routine, and how can I set it to run after 1 hour and another after 24 hour for a specific item not everything in db? 
Your help is appreciated

Comment: Possible of duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914571/cronjob-run-php-only-in-a-specified-interval-of-time

Answer (score 2):

Can't you do all of the work in your PHP file and mySQL database?

- Add a column to each post row called something like "time_added"
- Run the cron every hour.
- Query the database and check for posts older than 24 hours that don't have the correct status set to say that you already did something with them after 24 hours.
- Query the database and check for posts older than 1 hour that don't have the status set to say that you have already done something with them after 1 hour or 24 hours.
- Update the status of the posts.

Comment: A great idea. Let me try

Comment: Did that help at all?

Comment: Unfortunately someone has just maliciously downvoted my answer above along with all of my other answers on here going back 7 years.

Comment: Sorry bro. Don’t know why somebody would do that. Anyway i’ll let you know if this cones to success